# How to lock a function access from threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I've a code as below.

```
class main{
    main()
    {
        myThread1 mt1 = new myThread1();
        myThread2 mt2 = new myThread2();

        mt1.start();
        mt2.start();

        mt1.join();
        mt2.join()

        System.out.println(access.sb.toString());
    }
}

class myThread1{
    run(){
        access.grow(" IJKLMNOP ");
    }
}

class myThread2{
    run(){
        access.grow(" ABCDEFGH ");
    }
}

class access{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    void grow(str)
    {
        sb.append(str);
    }

}
```

**Ignore errors

Output:

```
 ABCDE IJKLMFGHFGH
```

Expected Output should be one after the other, or vice. I figured it out that, it is due to random access to function `grow` by both the threads. Is there any process so that I can allow access to function `grow` only one thread at an instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marking `grow` as [`synchronized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) will cause a particular instance of `access` to serialize calls to `grow` amongst threads:

```
synchronized void grow() {
    ...
}
```

Another approach would be to enqueue work onto some flavor of a thread-safe `Queue` (typically some kind of `BlockingQueue`) and then to read work from the queue on a different thread, but that might not be necessary given the context you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

For better performance use synchronize block

```
       void grow(str)

      {
          synchronize(sb){
            sb.append(str);
       }
       }
```

also u can use concurrency pkg lock class

```
      Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        void grow(str)

      {
          try{ lock.lock();
            sb.append(str);
        finally(){
           lock.unlock();
        }

       }
```